# Removing All Rows of a Dynamic Table but First Row

Tags: jquery, html-table

How can I use jQuery to remove all row from a dynamic table like this:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <th style="width:100px;">Barangays</th>
    <th style="width:140px;">Lat</th>
    <th style="width:140px;">long</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this code to append `<td>` to the table:

**JS CODE:**

```
 $('tr.' + this.id).html('<td>' + this.title + '</td><td>' + this.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6) + '</td><td>' + this.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6) + '</td>');
```

Now I need a click function to remove all added rows but keep the first row in the table like before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the HTML is invalid th should be the child of a `tr` element.

To remove the rows try

```
$('#myTable tr').slice(1).remove()
```

Change your html to

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Barangays</th>
            <th style="width:140px;">Lat</th>
            <th style="width:140px;">long</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').remove()
```

Comment: H Arun , thanks for your comment the $('#myTable tr').slice(1).remove() works , slow but it works but the second solution not working!

Comment: @Behseini for the second solution to work you need to change the html

Answer (score 3):

**Use this**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#myTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhtC8/)

**OR**

```
if ($("table tr").length != 1) {
     $("table tr:last").remove();
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are doing the right thing. OP wants to keep first row

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#myTable tr').not(':first').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `eq` of jquery

```
var first = $('#myTable tbody tr').eq(0); // Take the first row
$('#myTable tbody tr').remove(); //remove all rows
$('#myTable tbody').html(first); //put first row again
```

#### Demo